# Output the value of variable containing other variable in it in bash

Tags: bash, variables, output

I got these two lines in my script:

`a=2;for i in {c..k};do let a+=1; export disk${a}_device=/dev/sd$i;done`

`for i in {3..11}; do sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=$(echo $[disk${i}_device]) bs=512 count=1;done`

My issue is that echo $[disk${i}_device] substitutes to null and thus:
dd if=/dev/zero of= bs=512 count=1

What I'm trying to achieve is to:

`export disk3_device=/dev/sdc`

`export disk4_device=/dev/sdd`

`export disk5_device=/dev/sde`

.....

and then

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1`

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=512 count=1`

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde bs=512 count=1`

.....
e.t.c

However variable expansion doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest fix is to change this:

```
$(echo $[disk${i}_device])
```

to this:

```
$(eval echo \$disk${i}_device)
```

However, if you want to have a little fun with it, do this to create the commands:

```
find /dev/sd[c-k] -printf "dd if=/dev/zero of=%p bs=512 count=1\n"
```

Looks good? Then execute!

```
find /dev/sd[c-k] -printf "dd if=/dev/zero of=%p bs=512 count=1\n" | sudo sh
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Webb! Although I didn't quite get the \$$" construction but what's important to me is that it's working. :)

Comment: some of that was not necessary and i've simplified the answer. my understanding is that `echo \$disk${i}_device` produces e.g. the string `$disk3_device`, and eval evaluates it as an expression, producing e.g. `/dev/sdc`.

Comment: Thanks again. I kinda made slight modification to the above:

`find /dev/sd[c-k] -exec sudo dd if=/dev/zero of={} bs=512 count=1 \;`

Comment: `-exec` might be the canonical answer. however, for large `find` results sets, `| sh` becomes much faster, and can be drop-in replaced with `| parallel` for slower, cpu-heavy tasks that don't spend most of their time on i/o to a single disk. it also makes it easy to do a dry-run of the exact commands that will be run (take off the `| sh`) or to log them (`| tee a.log | sh`).

Comment: Agreed, however I'm not allowed to "sudo su" and "sudo sh" on that machine :)